# How can I make the aspect work on the method AService.methodB()?

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I define a aspect as follow:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ServiceMethodExecuteTimeAspect {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Pointcut("execution(* *.service.*.*(..))")
public void serviceMethod() {

}

@Around("serviceMethod()")
public Object executeTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object result;
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    long executeTime;
    long start;
    try {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executeTime = end - start;
        logger.debug("ServiceMethodExecuteTimeAspect class method:{}#{} execute time is:{}", proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName(), method.getName(), executeTime);
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        logger.error("ServiceMethodExecuteTimeAspect throw exception", throwable);
        throw throwable;
    }
}
}
```

And I have a Service class in a service package as follow:

```
package example.service;
@Service
public class AService{
    public void methodA(){methodB();}
    public void methodB(){}
}
```

then ,when create `AService` instance bean get the follow log:

```
DEBUG o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimizations to advised method: public example.AService.methodB();
```

Then a spring `component` invoke the `AService.methodA()` method and I want see the log execution time of `AService.methodA()` and also log the execution time of `AService.methodB()`,but I find it's only log execution time of `AService.methodA()`.

In an another word my `ServiceMethodExecuteTimeAspect` not work on `AService.methodB()` when I invoke `AService.methodA()`.

So how can I make the aspect work on the method `AService.methodB()` when I I invoke `AService.methodA()` method?

Comment: Then the explanation is simple: Proxy-based Spring AOP does not work with self-invocation because self-invocation does not use the aspect proxy but the original object wrapped by it, i.e. no aspect advice can be triggered. See also the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) (search for "self-invocation" in that chapter). The alternative would be to use full-fledged AspectJ if you need aspects to work with self-invoked code.

Answer (score 0):

A way can do it ,define another Service ,and move the method `methodB()` to it .